# Zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^4+X^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

trying to find ONE Zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^4+X^2+1)$.

I know so far that this is not a field since 
$$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ 
therefore is not irreducible hence not a field so there must be zero divisors. How do I approach this next to actually find one?

Comment: Presumably you mean to ask about $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]/(X^4 + X^2 +1)$, a quotient of the ring of polynomials over the binary field?

Comment: yes :) sorry im new to this place

Comment: Notice that over the binary field, the factors $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$ are the same.

Comment: You already found zero divisors: $(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)=x^4+x^2+1=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring is question is $\mathbb Z_2[u]$ with $u^4+u^2+1=0$.

As you have noticed, $(u^2+u+1)(u^2-u+1)=u^4+u^2+1=0$ and so $u^2+u+1$ is a zero divisor.

It remains to prove that $u^2+u+1\ne0$.